# document.createElement inconsistency for canvas between mobile and desktop browser in threejs project

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am building a game in threejs in which I have to load a large amount of scenes, and all the objects in these scenes have canvastextures. This works great on desktop browsers, but when I switch to mobile the first few scenes load fine, then I get a error when drawing to the canvas because the 2D context is null or I get no error and the canvas renders nothing. I know its the canvas because I have an overlay for debugging that shows the canvases I use for textures and the ones that arent loading are just blank. I have no idea where to go from here :(

Comment: Why are you using so many canvases? Can you use less? At [the bottom of this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-canvas-textures.html) it mentions how to use less canvases.

Comment: Would need some more explanation around the issue

Comment: I am building a vr tour application, so i need to use canvases for each scene. And on mobile it just doesnt work. I don't think the canvases are the issue? Or the use of them.